# Basics of probability theory - fifth graders homework

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If you write some four-digit numbers using the digits $1, 2, 3, 4,$ place them in the bag, what is the probability of getting the number, which is $4$ in the ones digit(first from the right side)?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  I'll make a guess:  "You draw the digits one by one, making a number from right to left (first draw is the units place, second the tens place, and so on).  What is the probability that the digit in the units place is the $4$?"  Assuming this is right then the answer is $\frac 14$ by symmetry.  But, honestly, the question is phrased so poorly that many other answers are plausible.

Comment: Thank you. I feel like the task is unfinished, just posted the question here to confirm my guess.

Comment: Given that it's a problem for kids, I'll bet my reading is right...it's the sort of thing you could actually set up so they could experiment with it.  But even so, the phrasing really needs to be clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quarter.  One half.  One.  Zero.  $0.179.$  None of the above.

I'm kidding a bit, but the probability is the ratio of the number of four-digit numbers that end in $4$ versus the total number of numbers in the bag:

$$P = \frac{N_{\text{end in 4}}}{N}$$

So if you put $1234, 2234, 4432, 4431, 4433$ in the bag, the probability is $0.4$.  If you put $4432, 1233, 1243$ in the bag, the probability is zero.  If you put $1234$ in the bag, the probability is one.  It depends crucially on which numbers are on the slips of paper in the bag.

Comment: I agree with you. For me, it looks like conditions of the problem unfinished.